# Using Roman Numeral Notation with Notes in the Bass (not figured bass)

Tags: chord-progressions, roman-numerals

I have a situation where I want to use Roman numerals to express a chord progression.  In the jazz Real Book, this would look something like this:

(key of A major)
A A/G A/F# A/E D

I imagine this looks familiar to many people here on this site.  The above is easy to read, but what if I want to use Roman numerals instead?  The below, using figured bass, would become complicated:

I I(4 2) I(?) I(6 4) IV

... or worse:

I I(4 2) vi(7) I(6 4) IV

Is there a proper way to write out a Roman numeral chord representation with a clearly chosen scale degree as the bass note?

Comment: Yes, it’s called Figured Bass.

Comment: No, I made mention twice that usual figured bass would not be a sufficient way to do this.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes And I have two examples above with figured bass.

Comment: Complications are normal. While the second inversion of V7 is often called V4/3, the fuller notation is actually V6/4/3.

Comment: Why is it necessary to shoe-horn the music into an outdated form of notation? Is this just a thought-exercise? Mild curiosity? Roman numerals show function (as do pop symbols, though differently). If your chords are functioning traditionally in local harmony, and the effect is essentially a "I" pedal, the other notes would be treated as non-harmonic passing tones (G & F#) and would likely be excluded from the analysis since the more important parts of the music in that context would be the root position and the 2nd inversion. We have different notation systems for different reasons.

Comment: I think it would be practical to have a way to do this.  I was listening to a song, and I didn't know the key of it, so I just started jotting down Roman numerals.  Then the 7-6-5 bass line came in, and I felt it was an important and functional aspect of the song, and I wanted to include it in the chart.  As I considered using traditional figured-bass inversion notation, I realized that I wish I knew of a simpler solution for this; one that was more intuitive and easier to read.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes, figure bass would require notating the bass on staff. I don't think that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - I wasn't suggesting the OP use figured bass? also this post is a bit old, yeah?

Comment: One might be tempted to write two Roman numerals separated by a slash, but notation such as V/ii is already used for something else: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_chord

Comment: Some notations are a bit confusing. For example, the "G" in "A/G" represents only one note, but "G" by itself represents three notes, and so does the "A" in "A/G".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no, there is no "proper" way, no conventional way to do this. I've never seen it.

But I would write: `I  I/b7  I/6  I/5  IV`, I have never seen anyone else do it this way, but for me it works.

It would be more correct to write VIm7 (or vi7 classical music style) in stead of I/6, but I/6 makes the movement in the bass more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The only complication I see is whether you have indicated the `G` you meant.

You wrote a `G` natural...

> (key of A major) A A/G A/F# A/E

...in the key of `A` major normally `G#` is used in the scale. If that were the bass tone `A/G#` the Roman numeral would be `I4/2`. But if the bass tone is really `G` natural that chord is properly `V/IV`.

The slashes get a bit confusing so I will use the actual word 'of' and bars to try to make things clear...

`A:   I   |   V4/2 of IV   |   vi7   |   I6/4`

Those would be the Roman numeral for the jazz symbols you gave.

Notice that I started with `A:` that's indicating the key. You really need to do this with Roman numeral analysis. Keep in mind a song may change key or even have an *ambiguous* key, in which case you should make sensible key change notations, or Roman numeral analysis may not be appropriate for music that isn't really in a key. Also, be aware of the various Roman numeral symbols for borrowed and secondary chords which bring in chromatic harmony. Things like `bVII` or `viio/ii` etc.

It's not a big deal, but the `V4/2 of IV` doesn't move to `IV` and is sort of *non-functional* for that reason. This may be one of those ambiguous key situation like I mentioned above. It's really just an `A` major chord with a Mixolydian flavored descending bass line. Roman numeral analysis symbols can be a bit cumbersome to describe that.

FWIW, proper *figured bass* is different from Roman numerals. Similar, but not the same. Best example case I think is the `I6/4` chord. In the key of `C` the figured bass would be a *notated* `G` and the figure `6/4`. Take note that the `I` of the Roman numeral system is indicating the *tonic*, but the notated `G` of figured bass is indicating a *dominant* tone. To super condense a bunch of history, the era of figured bass *did not recognize that chord as an inverted tonic chord*. It was a *dissonant fourth above the bass which required resolution*. Mixing a bit of old and new systems, when that dissonant (non-chord tone) fourth resolved by stepping down to a major third above the bass *then* the proper chord was formed and that chord was a *dominant*. Not sure this helps or makes sense, but my point is that Roman numeral analysis and figured bass are not the same.

Comment: I just added an edit, sorry that I left out that this leads to a IV. The G is natural after all. It's a big I IV progression, with passing tones in the bass that give the I its dominant quality and make it a V/IV.

Comment: This is very good info, MC. I'm really looking for a solution that is more contemporary. I think in terms of classical music, you nailed it though.

I wonder if carots are the answer. Something like (this is tough to type cleanly):
I I/^b7 I/^6 I/^5

Answer (score 0):

This passage leading from A (tonic):

-> to the subdominant D

would be interpreted as (in relation to D):

I:

-> (V2 iii7 V46) IV

Comment: Eh, there's really not a vi chord though. It's just a I7 with passing tones in the bass that lead to IV.

Comment: Yes, I‘ve overlooked in I2 would be a G#. I will chorrect this passage as A = secondary dominante to D